# How do I search value (with regex) in array and push search value to multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

From this array, I want parse value inside the brackets with regular expression,
I use this pattern => [([^]]+)]

```
Array
(
    [0] => [DATA_1_A]
    [1] => [DATA_1_B] [DATA_2_B]
    [2] => [DATA_1_C] [DATA_2_C] [DATA_3_C]
)
```

And push value to multidimensional array. 
Like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => DATA_1_A
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => DATA_1_B
            [1] => DATA_2_B
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => DATA_1_C
            [1] => DATA_2_C
            [2] => DATA_3_C
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and with regex and array_map:

```
$new = array_map(function($i) {
    if(preg_match_all('/\[([^\]]+)\]/', $i, $m)) return $m[1];
    return $i;  }, $arr);
```

[demo](https://eval.in/584336)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without regex, assuming your data format is consistent. Strip off the first and last brackets then split the line by `] [`:

```
$output = array();
foreach ($data as $line) {
    $line = trim($line, '[]');
    $output[] = explode('] [', $line);
}
```

[Example](https://eval.in/584347)

Or with regex using the pattern `~\b([\w_\d]+)\b~` to match word characters, digits and underscores:

```
$output = array();
foreach ($data as $line) {
    preg_match_all('~\b([\w_\d]+)\b~', $line, $matches);
    if (!empty($matches[1])) {
        $output[] = $matches[1];
    }
}
```

[Example](https://eval.in/584346)

Comment: `$line = trim($line, '[]');`

Answer (score 0):

```
$array; //your initial array
$output = []; //result array
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $output[$key] = explode("] [", substr($value, 1, -1));
}
```

Here we take the first and last bracket out and then split by "] [".